# Who came up with the term "Earthling"?

Tags: history-of, science-fiction-genre, terminology

Or, to make matters a bit more attainable, what is the earliest occurrence of the term attested in writing?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthling#History

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research. The answer is literally the first one that comes up when you google the word

Comment: Kind of embarrassing, yes. I didn't check Wikipedia, but I did search on this site beforehand (obviously without any hits as the answer is readily available on Wikipedia). That said, though, I would still argue that the many downvotes are a bit extreme for the following reason: when there's a question on SE and an answer consisted simply of a link to Wikipedia, that answer would be considered bad, since Wikipedia can change over time. Also, does the mere existence of the answer on Wikipedia (at this point in time) make the question bad? And wouldn't have 1 downvote be sufficient?

Comment: Evidently multiple users felt that your question was sufficiently poor as to merit their downvotes. As to whether there mere existence of an answer on wikipedia is enough to earn *my* downvote, the answer is a qualified no. My downvote was because the wikipedia link was the first result when I googled your own question title. The [next link down](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11465/what-is-the-origin-of-earthling) also answered it directly as did [the one below it](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/earthling) implying that you'd done zero independent research before posting.

Comment: No, you're right about the poor prior research (this was probably the first time I didn't search on google but exclusively on SciFi.SE prior to asking), but I'm still not sure that makes this a bad question. You could even argue that, apparently, the subject matter is interesting enough to be included in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: A better question would be something like *"I know that wikipedia says it's the first, but where is that proven?"*

Comment: Right, I've included that point in my own answer below. Then again, it's close to impossible to prove that no prior mention of a term exists anywhere, which is a much better reason why my question was bad.

Comment: Don't feel too bad about multiple downvotes. The seven people only gave you one DV each. :)

Comment: That said you could also delete and repost the question with better wording. I think there's a badge for deleting one's low voted question.

Comment: You're right about the "one DV each" -- but what I can't get my head around is that if you come to this question and you see it's already got 6 DVs, do you *really* have to downvote it a 7th time? I mean, you look at it and you think "Nah, six downvotes isn't enough - this question *stinks*! Clearly, this is a -7, if not -8! I need to do something here, it can't stand like that!"

Comment: True about the option of deleting the question. But, alternatively, I could also go over to Wikipedia and modify the entry on "Earthling" to not contain the answer to my question any more ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthling#History),

> the sense of "inhabitant of earth" is first attested in 1593

although no reference is given to back up this claim. However, the same entry also mentions a work from 1949 ("Red Planet" by Robert A. Heinlein), claimed to be the first work in science fiction literature to contain the term in its current meaning.